# Check if all reserved jobs have been completed using beanstalkc

Tags: beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I want one of my scripts to know if all of the remaining queued jobs in beanstalkd have been completed.

I'm currently planning to iterate through every job id and run peek() to see if anything is returned.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Checking if the number of reserved jobs and queued jobs are zero through a beanstalk client tells you when the remaining jobs have been completed.

Comment: How do you check the number of reserved jobs?